# Website Testing

Tags: html, hosting

Say I have a website called www.website.com, which is online and hosted.

I am currently working on a other website(lets call it wwww.website2.com) and would like to send it to someone so he can have a look at it.

The way how I want to do this, is basically create the following link:

www.website.com/website2 - From which he will be able to view the content of www.website2.com

I am not to sure how I can do that.

Would appreciate your help a lot.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you have the IP address of the www.website2.com, you can redirect from `/website2` to the ip address

Comment: please provide more clear description

Comment: @kostyan_SV I am trying to upload a second website on my current website server to send it to somebody who can then view it to give me some feedback.

Comment: @noobuntu easier alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a folder to www.website.com called "website2". Then go to: www.website.com/website2 and (when there is an index.html (or index.php) in that folder, it'll show you that website.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I just tried to do what you said and it didnt work - I created a new folder through the WEBFTP, uploaded the entire folder of website2 - But when I go on my browser and type: www.website.com/nameoffolder - I get the following error: You do not have permission to access the requested file on this server.

Comment: Change the read/write settings of the folder on your server.

Comment: I did mean in my last comment "read/write permissions". Did it help you out?